# Solving a backtracking question of N Queens

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I am currently trying to learn the topic of Backtracking in Java. It is really really confusing for me because I am stuck. 
The problem is to find ways in which N Queens can be placed in NxN Chess board so that none of the Queens can attack each other. A queen can attack in the same row, same column and diagonally. My code goes like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void putZero(int[][] board,int n){
         for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                board[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void printBoard(int[][] board,int n){
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                System.out.print(board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
         System.out.print("\n\n\n");
    }
    public static void SolveNQ(int n){
        int[][] board = new int[n][n];
        putZero(board,n);
        if(SolveQUtil(board,0,n)==true){
            printBoard(board,n);
        }
    }
    public static boolean isSafe(int row, int col, int[][] board,int n){
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<col;i++){
           if(board[row][i]==1)
            return false;
        } 
        for(i=row,j = col; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--){
        if(board[i][j]==1)
        return false;
        }
         for (i = row, j = col; j >= 0 && i < n; i++, j--) 
            if (board[i][j] == 1) 
                return false;

        return true;
    }
    public static boolean SolveQUtil(int[][] board, int col, int n){
        if(col>=n){
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(isSafe(i,col,board,n)==true){
                board[i][col]=1;
        boolean a = SolveQUtil(board,col+1,n);
        if(a==true)
                return true;
        else 
            board[i][col]=0;
        }  
    }   
        return false;

    }
     public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(`enter code here`System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();;
        SolveNQ(n);
     }
}
```

It is producing the result I want, but I am not understanding how this works. In my method SolveQUtil(), the method is called again which is "recursive". When col = 0 is called, the Q1 is placed at [0,0] as there are no existing queens. But when col = 1 is called recursively, it searches for the suitable place and returns 'true'. Now, isn't the SolveNQ() supposed to print the solution every time true is returned? When does it return false? How is this working? I am a beginner and can anyone please explain this to me, step by step? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`SolveNQ`, which does the printing, is not called recursively; `SolveQUtil`, which `SolveNQ` calls, and which does *not* print anything, is recursive.